# Force call paint after property changed

Tags: java, swing

How can I force `JLayerUI.paint` call after changing `loading` attribute, I tried calling `JLayer.repaint()` but it doesn't work. I tried summarizing the problem in the following code

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    JPanel panel;
    LoadingLayerUI layerUI;
    JLayer<JPanel> layer;

    public Test() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        layerUI = new LoadingLayerUI();
        layer = new JLayer<>(panel, layerUI);

        add(layer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    }

    private void loadPreview() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            getImagePreview();
        });
    }

    private void getImagePreview() {
        layerUI.activate(true);
        layer.repaint();
        // Start Long loading process
        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        // End process
        layerUI.activate(false);
        layer.repaint();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.loadPreview();
            test.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

class LoadingLayerUI extends LayerUI<JPanel> {

    private boolean loading;

    public void activate(boolean enabled) {
        loading = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        super.paint(g, c);
        if (!loading) {
            return;
        }

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        int w = c.getWidth();
        int h = c.getHeight();
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .5f));
        g2.setColor(new Color(53, 146, 196));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.drawString("Loading...", 100, 100);
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you call repaint? I think you'll need a complete example to demonstrate this.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: @matt I edited the question by giving approximately the part of the code that shows the problem.

Comment: @Progman Sorry, I edited the question and added the code that causes the problem.

Comment: You have a code segment which blocks the GUI thread for 6 seconds. During that time no change in the GUI will be visible.

Comment: @Progman OMG I feel stupid, instead of running that long process into Thread I executed it with EDT responsible for drawing GUI. Thanks :)